# WebStorm - Default shortcut update, current line number highlighting

Tags: intellij-idea, webstorm

I'm using WebStorm 2018.2.8. I have the following questions:

1. Search for a file is `Ctrl + Shift + N`, is there any way I can update this shortcut to other combination? If not can I update Search Anywhere (`Shift + Shift`) to search for file only?
2. I see upcoming patches have a feature where the line number of the current cursor is highlighted, can I trigger this on 2018.2.8? See below image, number 25 (where the cursor is) in later patches would be highlighted (the second image).

   [image]

   [image]

Thanks.

Comment: Shortcuts can be canged in "Settings | Keymap" (e.g. "Main Menu - Navigate - Go to file"). Could you please attach screenshot to clarify the second point?

Comment: Hi @y.bedrov, thank you, found it. Updated description for the second point. Also is there any way I can update the behaviour of default `Double Shift`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can assign a custom shortcut to **Search Everywhere** and **Go to file** actions in **Main menu | Navigate | Search Everywhere** (note: in 2018.x,  **Search Everywhere** is available in **Other** menu)
2. there is a **Line number on caret row** in **Settings | Editor | Color Scheme | General | Code** option, but it is missing in 2018.x; you can customize the background of **Caret row** in **Settings | Editor | Color Scheme | General | Editor** to make it more visible